# Prove that the direct sum of any collection of free $R$-modules is free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I've found plenty of answers to this, but none that I can understand, I'm a beginner and struggling.  One possible solution involves identifying the union of the bases as a basis, but I cannot quite grasp this concept.

Comment: Do you believe that a free $R$-module can be written as the direct sum of copies of $R$?

Comment: I'm still trying to grasp what a direct sum actually is, and I've got to hand this in in an hour, so I really don't have any intuition here

Comment: Umm...  A direct sum is the subset of the direct product with only finitely many elements different from zero.  If the direct sum has finite index set, then it's the same as the direct product.  If it has infinite index set, it's ... um ... the part with no chance of having interesting convergence trouble.  (Trying to come up with useful characterizations that leave time for the problem in under an hour...)

Comment: @user135732 if you find yourself struggling to understand concepts on hour before something is due, that is a sure sign you need to seek help earlier. Don't wait so long next time! Some ideas take a day or more to get comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

Both the direct sum (coproduct in the category of $R$-modules) and free module conditions are defined by universal properties.

> A module $F$ is ***free*** on the set $X$ (the basis) if for any other $R$-module $M$ and any set map $\varphi: X \to M$, there is an $R$-module homomorphism $\bar{\varphi}: F \to M$ such that $\varphi = \bar{\varphi} \circ i$, where $i: X \to F$ is the inclusion of the set into the free module $F$.  *In other words, you say where the free generators go, and you have defined a homomorphism from the free module.*

$ $

> The ***direct sum*** of a collection of modules $\left\{ F_\alpha \right\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is the module $\oplus_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha$, together with a collection of injections $\iota_{\alpha}:  F_{\alpha} \to \oplus_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha$, such that for any other $R$-module $M$ and $R$-module homomorphisms $\psi_{\alpha}: F_\alpha \to M$, there exists a unique map $\psi:  \oplus_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha \to M$ such that $\psi_{\alpha} = \psi \circ \iota_{\alpha}$.  *In other words, defining a map from each of a collection of modules to a fixed target module is equivalent to defining a map from their direct sum.*

Say that you have a collection $\left\{ F_\alpha \right\}_{\alpha \in A}$ of free $R$-modules.  How do we show that the direct sum $\oplus_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha$ is free?  We need to come up with a candidate basis set and check that the universal property holds for this set.  Remember that for each $\alpha \in A$, $F_{\alpha}$ is free, so it has a basis set, say $X_{\alpha}$.  Let's define the set
$$
X = \bigsqcup_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}
$$
and show that it is a basis for $\oplus_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha$.  It's clear that we have the set inclusion $i:  X \to \oplus_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha$ by defining $i \big|_{X_{\alpha}} = i_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha \in A$.

To show that $X$ is a basis, fix an arbitrary $R$-module $M$ and choose a set map $\varphi:  X \to M$.  This is equivalent to choosing, for each $\alpha \in A$, a map $\varphi_{\alpha}:  X_{\alpha} \to M$.  Because each $F_{\alpha}$ is free, we have a homomorphism $\bar{\varphi}_{\alpha}:  F_{\alpha} \to M$ satisfying $\varphi_{\alpha} = \bar{\varphi}_{\alpha} \circ i_{\alpha}$.

Now, by the universal property of the direct sum, we have a homomorphism $\bar{\varphi}:  \oplus_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha \to M$ satisfying $\bar{\varphi}_{\alpha} = \bar{\varphi} \circ \iota_{\alpha}$.  Now, we may conclude that $\varphi = \bar{\varphi} \circ i$, as desired.